# jquery highlight doesn't cover the whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function to highlight the entire contents of a div:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        $("<div/>")
        .width(el.width())
        .height(el.height())
        .css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": el.offset().left,
            "top": el.offset().top,
            "background-color": "#ffff99",
            "opacity": ".7",
            "z-index": "9999999"
        }).appendTo('body').fadeOut(1000).queue(function () { $(this).remove(); });
    });
}
```

The problem is with content loaded via some AJAX call, it will only highlight say the very top of the div. I assume due to it not knowing at that time how large the content will be.

I might do something like this to preview:

```
$('#preview_text_button').click(function()
{
    var text = $('.texarea').val();
    $('#preview').load('page address', {'text':text});
    $('.preview').show();
    $('.preview').highlight();
});
```

What I'm asking is: How do I get the highlight to cover the entire thing? I thought including it last would do it, but it appears not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by using `jQuery.load()`, you are making an asynchronous call. This means that the data is being loaded without blocking the rest of the script. Instead of running it immediately after, you need to pass a callback to the `.load` function like this:

```
$('#preview_text_button').click(function()
{
    var text = $('.texarea').val();
    $('#preview').load('page address', {'text':text}, function() {
        $('.preview').show();
        $('.preview').highlight();
    });
});
```

Read more of `.load()` here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

I would also look into what `AJAX` is and how it works. I usually trust MDN for answers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. As you've identified, you're setting the size of the `div` *before* adding the text. With your curent approach, you'll need to set it (or update it) after the text is loaded (by using `load`'s completion callback).
2. You'll probably want [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) and [`outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/).
3. If the user resizes the browser window, your highlight is likely to get misaligned.
4. `this` in a jQuery plugin is **already** a jQuery object. No need to use `$()` on it.
5. jQuery plugins should always return `this` unless they have a good reason not to.

Instead, consider inserting the `div` in the content (not `body`), with `position: absolute` and `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` set to `0`. Make sure the element its in is `position: relative` (or otherwise positioned.) Have a second `div` in the target area where the text is actually loaded.

Here's an example. I wasn't sure why you used `.prefix` rather than `#preview` for the last two lines, so I changed it:

```js
jQuery.fn.highlight = function () {
    // Added return, removed $()
    return this.each(function () {
        $("<div/>")
        .css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            "background-color": "#ffff99",
            opacity: .7,
            "z-index": 9999999
        }).prependTo(this).fadeOut(1000).queue(function () { $(this).remove(); });
    });
};

// Just to emulate `load`
jQuery.fn.fakeLoad = function(url, data, callback) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
      callback.call(this);
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
};

$('#preview_text_button').click(function()
{
    var text = $('.texarea').val();
    // The div to contain the content
    var div = $("<div/>");
    // Clear previous #preview contents, just have our contents div
    $('#preview').html(div);
    // Do the load
    div.fakeLoad('page address', {'text':text}, function() {
      // We have the text, show it and do the highlight thing
      $('#preview').show().highlight();
    });
});
```

```css
#preview {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>When you click the button, after a random delay some text is loaded and highlighted (briefly)</div>
<input type="button" id="preview_text_button" value="Click Me">
<div>Some text before the preview</div>
<div id="preview"></div>
<div>Some text after the preview</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, you don't do it the last thing. You put an AJAX request, then call .show() and .highlight() and an AJAX request actually shoots and puts content into your DOM **later**. Your show() and .highlight must be in a callback in a .load() call.

PS I am also not sure why do you use such a difficult JS way when you could do it with CSS and pseudoelements, then just add a class to elements you want to highlight.

Comment: About the JS, it's because it's highlighting it with a blink, not a solid CSS change. If you have a better idea using simple CSS changes, fire away :)

Comment: CSS transitions and animations are supported very well by browsers right now, so you definitely can pack blinking into CSS as well.